# Adding "edit" in a comment creates link to edit

Tags: support, comments

I wanted to make an edit to a comment I made on a question, so I edited the comment and put "edit [insert edit text here]". Now I'm not sure if this was intentional for UX, but the "edit" in my comment becomes an edit link for the post.

Is this intentional behaviour for new UX or a legitimate bug?

Link to question as reference: (It got deleted, question name was "[javascript] - What will the code below output to the console and why?")

Comment: Comments will replace the text `[edit]` with a link to edit the post you commented on.

Comment: ah... well thats pretty cool. what a great first question. one more thing is i didnt have square brackets around my edit. what's the case for that

Comment: They are [magic links](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: There are a lot of questions with that title every day. The title says nothing. Still, if you can link to it high-reputation users will be able to see it.

Comment: There's very little reason to annotate your edits with the word "edit." Pretty much no one cares. Comments can only be edited within the first five minutes anyway, the odds that someone read the comment before you edited it and then came back to see the edit afterwards are vanishingly small. Saying "edit" in a Question / Answer is also something that gets edited out: there's already a revision history people can look at if they're interested in seeing edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You posted the following comment:

```
you could have just tried this yourself unless you think this is puzzle 
SE for coding... [edit] doesn't even compile...
```

(broken across two lines for readability). The `[edit]` in there is *meant* to become a link, see the [comment formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting):

> Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available[.]
>
> [...]
>
> Supported shorthand links:
>
> - [...]
> - `[edit]` – link to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).

Comment: ah... could've sworn i didnt put `[edit]` but might just be auto appending it? idk might be going crazy. thanks